# Not retrieving data tables properly with Python pandas / urllib3

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to pull datatables from this website and cannot seem to get the table: https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/us/nv/north-las-vegas/KVGT/date/2021-8-26

I first tried calling pd.read_html(url), where the url variable is the link above.  This returns no tables error.

I then tried to access the website using urllib3 and parsing with bs4, like so:

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/us/nv/north-las-vegas/KVGT/date/2021-8-26'
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.data)

list_of_tables = soup.find_all('table')
```

where list_of_tables returns an empty list.  Can anyone help me retrieve the table with all the hourly weather data as I am not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information in that page is loaded dynamically, from an API. You can inspect the Network tab in Dev tools, to inspect the network calls.
One way of getting a table from that page would be:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://api.weather.com/v1/location/KVGT:9:US/observations/historical.json?apiKey=e1f10a1e78da46f5b10a1e78da96f525&units=e&startDate=20210826&endDate=20210826')
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['observations'])
df
```

This returns a dataframe with historical data:

```
key class   expire_time_gmt obs_id  obs_name    valid_time_gmt  day_ind temp    wx_icon icon_extd   wx_phrase   pressure_tend   pressure_desc   dewPt   heat_index  rh  pressure    vis wc  wdir    wdir_cardinal   gust    wspd    max_temp    min_temp    precip_total    precip_hrly snow_hrly   uv_desc feels_like  uv_index    qualifier   qualifier_svrty blunt_phrase    terse_phrase    clds    water_temp  primary_wave_period primary_wave_height primary_swell_period    primary_swell_height    primary_swell_direction secondary_swell_period  secondary_swell_height  secondary_swell_direction
0   KVGT    observation 1629971580  KVGT    Las Vegas   1629964380  N   93  33  3300    Fair    NaN None    40  89  16  27.56   10  93  190.0   S   NaN 12  107.0   76.0    None    0   None    Low 89  0   None    None    None    None    CLR None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
1   KVGT    observation 1629975180  KVGT    Las Vegas   1629967980  N   93  33  3300    Fair    2.0 Falling Rapidly 41  89  16  27.55   10  93  260.0   W   NaN 8   NaN NaN None    0   None    Low 89  0   None    None    None    None    CLR None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
2   KVGT    observation 1629978780  KVGT    Las Vegas   1629971580  N   90  33  3300    Fair    NaN None    43  86  19  27.55   10  90  210.0   SSW NaN 6   NaN NaN None    0   None    Low 86  0   None    None    None    None    CLR None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
3   KVGT    observation 1629982380  KVGT    Las Vegas   1629975180  N   86  33  3300    Fair    NaN None    41  83  20  27.56   10  86  310.0   NW  NaN 3   NaN NaN None    0   None    Low 83  0   None    None    None    None    CLR None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
[....]
```

For daily observations data, the url you would need to scrape is `https://api.weather.com/v1/location/KVGT:9:US/almanac/daily.json?apiKey=e1f10a1e78da46f5b10a1e78da96f525&units=e&start=0826`

You can install requests with `pip install requests`, and pandas with `pip install pandas`

Comment: Thank for the great response!  I'll have to add a feature that enables me to loop through many dates (thus waiting day to day as only 500 calls are allowed).

Answer (score 0):

so I have been experimenting with the selenium package for web scraping and found some very concise code to solve this task.  I have also gone ahead and added in code that answers my second question to the first response (hiding the browser on execution).

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import pandas as pd
import time

executable_path = '.\chromedriver.exe' # your respective path
url = f'https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/us/nv/north-las-vegas/KVGT/date/2020-01-01'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True             # dont open browser

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path, options=options)

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)
html = driver.page_source
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
driver.close()

df = df_list[-1].dropna()
'''
```